# SSL shows valid for domain.com but invalid for domain with https

Tags: http, https, ssl-certificate, tomcat6

I have installed SSL certificates 1 year ago and it was working fine for a few days ago but now it shows following error:

`The URL couldn't be validated. Callback verification failed with the following errors: curl_errno = 60; curl_error = SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate; HTTP Status Code = 200; HTTP Message = Connection established`

And when I check on SSL Checker for `https//domain.com`, it says,

`The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate. Learn more about this error. You can fix this by following Entrust's Certificate Installation Instructions for your server platform. Pay attention to the parts about Intermediate certificates.`

But when I check only `domain.com` on SSL checker, it says

`The hostname (domain.com) is correctly listed in the certificate.`

All certificates are installed even intermediate certificates but problem is not solved.

Server is Tomcat 6.

Comment: How about to show certificate? It is public anyway

Comment: @dmitry ssl certificates are installed on clint server, even i cant see them.. but they shown me the certificates installed via screenshots, but when i check on ssl checker its gives the above error, so i was confused what could be error here... honestly i am new for ssl installation and troubleshooting, so thought to take help here..

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer great!.. i appreciate that you shared your post with me.. but here i came for a solution and its urgent(fyi).. and its urgent because my client is suffering from a long time because of this and my team tried everything they could to sort this out.. but they cant. So i decided to come here for help. if you have solution for above then tell me because your post surely is not a solution for my current situation. i hope you get why i said urgent.

Comment: No. It is urgent for you and for your client, but **it is not urgent for anyone else**. You cannot make it so, since people have their own deadlines, and moreover, they are here at their leisure. Please read the whole of the link I have supplied, and note that this is an issue of basic manners, and not a rule specific to Stack Overflow. I will be flagging to a moderator if you add that back in again.

Comment: @halfer yeah its urgent for me thats why i added please help with that... i didnt said its urgent for you or anybody. its urgent for me thatsy i said its urgent. And about flagging to moderator.. i dont think i abused anyone or i did anything wrong because adding urgent is not some part of rule on stack over flow, its you who want to control others post as per your thinking. its just request to give solution as early possible. you can do whatever you want. i have valid explanation for same.

Comment: The purpose of adding "urgent" is to pressure volunteers to give answers that they do not have time for. You will not last long here if you continue to believe your questions are more important than the others that came in on the same day. Reported.

Comment: @halfer you think its pressure but according to me its request. And i added its urgent not because my question is more important, i added urgent because i am in some problem and that problem is less time to solve it. You are just taking it to wrong direction. But anyways moderator will look into this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL certificates regenerated from provider and issue resolved.